# jekyll error building page related to kramdown parser

Tags: jekyll

Whenever I run the `bundle exec jekyll serve` it returns the error

```
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have kramdown-parser-gfm or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- kramdown-parser-gfm' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!   
  Liquid Exception: kramdown-parser-gfm in /_layouts/default.html
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    kramdown-parser-gfm
```

so, I tried `gem install kramdown-parser-gfm`, but it returns the same error after that.
I also tried to remove and reinstall the jekyll and bundle, but didn't work either.

```
jekyll version 3.9.0 Bundler version 2.1.4
```

Comment: I haven't used Jekyll on my machine in a while, and I also have this issue on 10.15.6; reinstalling Jekyll and uninstalling and reinstalling all gems didn't help.

Comment: @cdf1982 Yeah It didn't work for me either

Comment: I believe this may be due to the Github-suggested security fix for the flagged vulnerability in Kramdown, `Bump kramdown from 1.17.0 to 2.3.0`. It was after I applied this that this error popped up. The solution below fixed it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I added `gem "kramdown-parser-gfm"` to the `Gemfile` and then ran `bundle install`.

Now the serve command completes successfully.

Comment: I add the same issue, and this fix it!

Answer (score 9):

1. delete the Gemfile.lock file
2. go to gem file add  `gem "kramdown-parser-gfm"`
3. open terminal and give command `bundler`
4. after install all packages, in terminal give command `bundle exec jekyll serve`
   I hope application will run properly now.

Comment: No need to delete the `Gemfile.lock` file. It will be updated when you run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 1):

### On Windows

If you open your gemfile, you will notice the following.

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.2.1"
```

If you have the specific jekyll version and after running "bundler", you will receive the following errors.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "kramdown":
  In Gemfile:
    jekyll (~> 3.2.1) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
      kramdown (~> 1.3)

    kramdown-parser-gfm was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
```

Remove the specific version of jekyll, like so:

```
gem "jekyll"
```

Do not forget to add webrick gem to gemfile

```
gem "webrick"
```

Run bundler again.

```
bundler
```

Finally, serve

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add:

```
gem "rexml"
```

to the Gemfile.